# Can I use the Chi Squared Test on percentages?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, chi-squared

I am writing a program where I want to check the fit of some data to a distribution through the Chi Squared test. The data is relative frequency, so could I use the percentages in each cell from the data and expected percentage in cell in place of the number of times the data is in each cell in the data set?

Comment: No, you cannot use percentages because the two tables $T_1 = \left[\begin{matrix} 2 &8 \\ 3&7\end{matrix}\right]$ and $T_2 = \left[\begin{matrix} 2000 & 8000 \\300 & 700\end{matrix}\right]$ have the same row percentages but the significance changes drastically.

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot!